# How to call subclass's method from superclass's object?

Tags: c#-3.0

In the following simple code, I am trying to access method 'PrintMessage' which is defined in the SubClass. I created an object of SuperClass and initiated an instance of SubClass into this. I want to understand why this is wrong?

I am getting the following error on executing the code.

Error   1   '.SuperClass' does not contain a definition for 'PrintMessage' and no extension method 'PrintMessage' accepting a first argument of type 'SuperClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SuperClass objSuperClass = new SubClass();

            //The following statement gives me error
            objSuperClass.PrintMessage();

        }
    }

    public abstract class SuperClass 
    {

    }

    public class SubClass : SuperClass
    {
        public void PrintMessage()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any base class definition or implementation of "PrintMessage". Either define an abstract/concrete "PrintMethod" in the base class and override the same in the subclass.

Cheers,
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

U can cast `objSuperClass` to `SubClass` and will be able to call subclass method in following way

```
((SubClass)objSuperClass).PrintMessage();
```

If you want, can go through [this](http://pastebin.com/HZ7bzVAV) . (Modified version of your code)